# Listbox Scrolling in WP7.5 Mango apps like foursquare and facebook

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, itemscontrol

I am working on an app which shows the search results based on the query you type. And I am adding infinite scroll to this. In WP7.5 there are Vertical compression and horizontal compression events on a listbox where we can start fetching the results and update the ItemsControl or Listbox. And parallel to this I have layouts with variable heights which is making the listbox to recalculate the heights while scrolling and it flickers during this time since vitualization doesn't work in this scenario.

But, the way it is done in apps like foursquare and facebook is very interesting. The list box is left with some empty space in the end when it reaches the end and the results then are added to the end filling the empty space. And infinite scroll attained is very nice with no flickering. And when we scroll upwards the controls are being loaded without the data but the heading. Is this helping the listbox for not recalculating layout heights when there are multi sized layouts. Can some one explain me how they are doing if anyone has figured it out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of calculating height every time, why not just use a stack panel with height="auto" and what every your data comes in it. create a user control and add in it at runtime. make your life easy this way. ( not empty spacing, auto scrolling and height calculation)

and for four square boxes, it will be inside your user control

Comment: See the problem comes when there is a heavy scrolling the data should not disappear for recycling. So virtualization should be selective so that only header is displayed. And I did not understand the part of four square boxes you mentioned.